# How to get roles assigned for an user in Office 365 environment from Powerapps

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365, powerapps, security-roles

We are trying to change Button Visibility Based on User Role. Added Custom Security Role, Assigned roles to Users from Dynamics 365 environment .

[Custom Security roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCvPR.png)

Assigned These roles to Users via Manage Roles option.

[Manage User Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTxOj.png)

How can we get Role assigned for CurrentUser in Powerapps Environment? Only 3 attributes(Email,fullName,Image) are available for User() object. Tried using Dynamics 365 Users, Security roles etc into Datasource. Also tried by adding Users entity into Datasource.

[Dynamics 365 security roles, users in to datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87SRE.png)

Comment: Do you have any followup question?

Answer (score 0):

In a classic Dynamics CRM web UI or Model driven PowerApp, we have a choice to write client side form scripting to pull current user’s security roles and manipulate the client controls. We will be using web api or odata & utilize the `systemuserrolescollection` or `SystemUserRolesSet` dataset to pull the needed data. [Read more](http://sharathdozen.blogspot.com/2017/09/data-retrieval-techniques-in-dynamics.html?m=1)

But in Canvas apps, even today we are unable to find this `System user roles` table in Dynamics 365 connectors. So we have to wait till this is exposed.

Or you can have a SQL replication (maybe Data export service) or custom connector which consume the [D365 web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/entities/systemuserroles) to pull this data.

Comment: Has anything about how Canvas apps interact with the D365 tables changed in the last year as far as this data being exposed?

Comment: @ChristopherKlein I have to check, there were revision/different versions of connector came after that

Comment: @ChristopherKlein nah, this is not yet available. Probably you can execute Flow from PowerApps, query using the fetchxml in Flow & return the  array to PowerApps and finish the task. https://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/using-fetchxml-in-the-flows/ and https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/return-an-array-from-flow-to-powerapps-response-method/