# How to get MyTeams of CurrentUser in Office 365(Dynamics 365) Environment from Powerapps?

Tags: security, dynamics-crm, office365, powerapps

How to get **MyTeams** of CurrentUser in Office 365(Dynamics 365) Environment from **Powerapps** ?

We are trying to check whether the CurrentUser is a member of a particular Team or not. Teams are added from **Dynamics** 365 environment.

We can get all existing teams by adding 'Teams' entity into Datasource.But we need  currentUser's team. Powerapps showing "MyTeams" option in Entity page. But no such option available in code.

[Teams in Dynamics 365 enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzzjN.png)

[Myteams Option in Powerapps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKWSU.png)

Comment: Do you got any followup question?

Answer (score 0):

Like I answered in your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54273563/7920473), we will be doing such queries using web api in client side form scripting.

This [TeamMembership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/entities/teammembership) entity is not listing in PowerApps D365 connector, so alternate solution is custom connector to consume the needed crm web api call. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/218804)